# Custom HTTP Status Code other than Registered Status Code

Tags: spring, http

I am trying to use a custom HTTP Status Code (450) but I get an error "org.springframework.http.HttpStatus doesn't have any enum constant '450' defined". I tried searching the other threads, but I wasn't able to find a suitable reply to my situation. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please find below my code:

```
<http:inbound-gateway supported-methods="POST"
        request-channel="headerEnricher"
        error-channel="errorHandlerRouterChannel"
        reply-channel="responseChannel" header-mapper="headerMapper"
        path="/testApi/1.0" request-payload-type="java.lang.String" />
```

Error handler method:

```
private Message<String> createErrorResponse() {
        Map<String, String> respHeader = new HashMap<String, String>();
        respHeader.put(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, "450");
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Validation Error")
                .copyHeaders(respHeader).build();
}
```

Error Exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [450]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [450]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [450]
    org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:426)
    org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.resolveHttpStatusFromHeaders(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:549)
    org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.setupResponseAndConvertReply(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:443)
    org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:103)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
```

Comment: What situation is that? I would tend to avoid a custom http status code in most cases I can think of.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150176/custom-http-code-with-spring-mvc

Comment: Hi Aldanux, thanks for the reply. But please have a look at my code. Please let me know how to handle this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Here I am trying to create a Message Response using Message Builder. And our requirement is not to use the generic Business Validation Status Code 400 and use the customized code 450. But using a 450 is throwing an error as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) I would argue that Spring is buggy when it only supports a hard-wired set of status codes; these are an extension point in HTTP and thus the set of status code is open-ended (well, until the range 100..599 has been filled up).

b) With respect to your use case -- maybe you could just use status code 422 instead (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422)?